# Duplicate data when inserting a ManyToMany JPA entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

When adding an entity that stores other entities in itself, they are added without checking their existence in the database. That is, if I add a leakSource that includes CompEmails that already exist in the table, they are duplicated, and the existing ones are non-linked to the leakSource. Tell me how to fix it?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comp_emails")
class CompEmails (
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long? = null,

    val address: String? = null,

    @ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE], mappedBy = "compEmails")
    val leakSources: Set<LeakSource>? = null
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "leak_source")
class LeakSource (
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long? = null,

    val source: String? = null,

    @ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE])
    @JoinTable(
        name = "comp_emails_sites_alert",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "source_id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "email_id")]
    )
    val compEmails: Set<CompEmails>? = null
)

@PostMapping("/add-leak-source")
    fun addLeakSource(@RequestBody leakSource: LeakSource) : LeakSource {
        leakSourceRepo.save(leakSource)
        return leakSourceRepo.getById(leakSource.id!!)
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by duplicated? It is ManyToMany relationship, so you can expect each LeakSource to have multiple CompEmails. And also
`LeakSource` is the owning entity here, so `cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE]` shouldn't present in CompEmails class

Answer (score 0):

LeakSource is the owner side of the relationship. Whenever you try adding a CompEmail to a LeakSource, you should do the following steps given order.

**1- If CompEmail exists in db: fetch it**

**if not: create it, save to db and fetch the saved entity**

```
compEmail = getById(ceId);
// or
... create compEmail
compEmail = save(compEmail);
```

**2- If LeakSource exists in db: fetch it**

**if not: create it, save to db and fetch the saved entity**

```
leakSource = getById(lsId);
// or
... create leakSource
leakSource = save(leakSource);
```

**3- Add CompEmail to LeakSource's CompEmail list. It should look like this:**

```
...
leakSource.getCompEmails().add(compEmail);
```

**4- Save the LeakSource entity (which we just added the CompEmail)**

**Additional notes:**

`cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE]`
This property should be removed from `CompEmails`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`
try to make without  `@GeneratedValue`, because you want to add records to the exist value not to add another one with differnt id.